# sending data to hashicorp vault dynamically using ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, hashicorp-vault

I want to write/store data in `Hasicorp` vault using Ansible. I have the working code for that. But the problem is I have to store creds in the `Hasicorp` vault in a dynamic way.
Depending on the service sometimes we have to store 1 secret, sometimes 2 secrets, or sometimes 3 using the same ansible script.

Eg:
For Cassandra 3 secrets:
keyspace
password
username

For RdsPostgreSql for 2 secrets:
host
port

For SSHConfig 1 secrets:
ssh-key

My ansible code:

```
- name: Get secrets from Vault
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Write a value to the cubbyhole via the remote host with userpass auth
    community.hashi_vault.vault_kv2_write:
      url: http://127.0.0.1:8200
      path: "{{ path_to_secret }}"
      data:
        "{{ secret_key_1 }}": "{{ secret_val_1 }}"
        "{{ secret_key_2 }}":  "{{ secret_val_2 }}"
      auth_method: token
      token:  "{{ auth_token }}"
    register: result

  - name: Echo the secret_data
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

So in this code how do I make the key/value pairs that I am sending under `data` dynamic? Like sending one or more dictionary depending on service.
I have to send the key/value pairs at run time using `--extra-vars`

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear to me... Does it work on the command line? Help us help you with a question that would read like: I want to replicate the following command line in Ansible. Here is what I got so far but ... +Why would you use the Cubbyhole at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you send the full dict directly as a var?

```yaml
  - name: Write a value to the cubbyhole via the remote host with userpass auth
    community.hashi_vault.vault_kv2_write:
      url: http://127.0.0.1:8200
      path: "{{ path_to_secret }}"
      data: "{{ my_data_dict }}"
      auth_method: token
      token:  "{{ auth_token }}"
    register: result
```

You can then call this with an extra var from the command line:

```
ansible-playbook -e '{"my_data_dict": {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}}' \
  my_playbook.yml
```

To ease your life a bit (since writing json inline like above is somewhat error prone), you can set the given dictionary in a separate yaml file, e.g. `my_data_dict.yml`

```yaml
---
my_data_dict:
  toto: earth
  pipo: wind
  bingo: fire
```

and send the vars declared in that file as extra vars from the command line:

```
ansible-playbook -e @my_data_dict.yml my_playbook.yml
```